# What is the best site/tool/way for finding the RSZ values of a bitcoin transaction?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, signature, raw-transaction, ecdsa

The two most popular sites for doing this are down which are https://2coin.org/ and https://2xoin.com/getRSZfromRawTX/ with no indication they'll ever return to be usable.

Can anyone here link any other sites, tools or ways to find and list the RSZ values of a bitcoin transaction?

Comment: This sounds like a case of the XY problem. What do you need this values for? On themselves, they aren't useful, but they could be a means to solve a bigger problem (like e.g. debugging signer software you're writing). What is that bigger problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Pieter. That's a great question I'll give a detailed answer to. I'm not debugging any signer software I'd just like those values(RSZ) listed from transactions. The hex/raw transaction has them as a whole but it's hard reading through a transaction and identifying the exact values. Every transaction has these values for everyone to see but I'd like them to organized so I don't have to sort through the scripts. I'd just like to know the values for analysis of any repeated variables/sigs. The problem here is I don't know how to. Let me know if you have an answer for me.

Comment: Are you trying to find repeated nonces, so you can derive private keys for those transactions?

Comment: Yep. But I don't know what you mean by nonces. I hope you're referring to the repeated values(k,r,etc). (I hit enter and this prematurely sends my messages even though I'm just trying to ident them so I have to reedit them to add more content) I need a consistent working site/tool/script/method for doing this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes. Thank you both for your support.